# Pygame: How to use the get_rect function to change the width of an image?

Tags: python, pygame

I am learning how to use and manipulate images in pygame. I've learned how to move images on a screen, but I'm not sure how to change the width and the height of an image with the `get_rect` function. I assumed it would be similar to centering an image in syntax, but that didn't seem to work when I tried it out.

Here's what I tried:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init() 

screen_size = [500, 500]

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_size[0], screen_size[1]])

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True 
while running:
    clock.tick(20)
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    
    
    IMAGE = image.load('image.png').convert()  
    rect = IMAGE.get_rect(width=10)
    screen.blit(IMAGE, rect)

    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who answers this

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the width or height of an image with [`get_rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect). If you want to change the size of an image, you have to use [`pygame.transform.scale`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale) or [`pygame.transform.smoothscale`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale):

```py
scaled_image = pygame.transform.smoothscale(IMAGE, (10, 10)
screen.blit(scaled_image, (x, y))
```